# Package function to perform operation on different "sets" of data in same dataframe

Tags: r

The ubiquitous `dplyr` package has the function `mutate_at` (and many other `*_at()`'s), which allows us to perform a similar operation on multiple columns. Using `purrr`-style formulas, the relevant column is indicated by `.`:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(colA, colB, colC), ~ 2 * .)
```

This would double the values in the respective columns.

However, some times we want to perform operations on multiple "sets" of columns at once. For example, given the following data.frame, we may want to perform `a * b` for `data1` and `data2`, and then store the respective results in columns called `data1` and `data2`:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    library(dplyr)
})

set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
    id      = 1:5,
    a_data1 = runif(5),
    a_data2 = runif(5),
    b_data1 = runif(5),
    b_data2 = runif(5),
    static  = runif(5)
)
```

For this trivial case, it wouldn't be too hard to simply do this by hand:

```
df %>%
    mutate(
        data1 = a_data1 * b_data1,
        data2 = a_data2 * b_data2,
    )
#>   id   a_data1   a_data2   b_data1   b_data2     static     data1      data2
#> 1  1 0.9148060 0.5190959 0.4577418 0.9400145 0.90403139 0.4187449 0.48795773
#> 2  2 0.9370754 0.7365883 0.7191123 0.9782264 0.13871017 0.6738624 0.72055016
#> 3  3 0.2861395 0.1346666 0.9346722 0.1174874 0.98889173 0.2674467 0.01582162
#> 4  4 0.8304476 0.6569923 0.2554288 0.4749971 0.94666823 0.2121203 0.31206942
#> 5  5 0.6417455 0.7050648 0.4622928 0.5603327 0.08243756 0.2966743 0.39507089
```

But this would get tiresome with many different "sets".

Another, "tidier" option would be to reshape our table:

```
df %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(
        cols = c(-id, -static),
        names_to = c('.value', 'grp'),
        names_sep = "_"
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        result = a * b
    ) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_wider(
        id_cols = c(id, static),
        names_from = grp,
        values_from = c(a, b, result)
    )
#> # A tibble: 5 x 8
#>      id static a_data1 a_data2 b_data1 b_data2 result_data1 result_data2
#>   <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1     1 0.904    0.915   0.519   0.458   0.940        0.419       0.488 
#> 2     2 0.139    0.937   0.737   0.719   0.978        0.674       0.721 
#> 3     3 0.989    0.286   0.135   0.935   0.117        0.267       0.0158
#> 4     4 0.947    0.830   0.657   0.255   0.475        0.212       0.312 
#> 5     5 0.0824   0.642   0.705   0.462   0.560        0.297       0.395
```

However, this involves two dataframe reshapes, which can kill performance (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60677042/2175231) I asked while developing the code below and the performance tests in the answer). Also, it changes the order of the columns (makes `static` the second column) which annoys me.

So I wrote the following function `mutateSet` which is currently part of my personal "utilities" package:

```
mutateSet <- function(df, colNames, formula,
                      isPrefix = TRUE,
                      separator = "_") {
  vars <- all.vars(formula)

  # extracts names wrapped in `.()`
  escapedNames <- function (expr)
  {
    unquote <- function(e) {
      if (is.pairlist(e) || length(e) <= 1L) NULL
      else if (e[[1L]] == as.name("."))      deparse(e[[2L]])
      else                                   unlist(sapply(e, unquote))
    }
    unquote(substitute(expr))
  }

  escapedVars <- eval(rlang::expr(escapedNames(!!formula)))

  # remove escaped names from mapping variables
  vars <- setdiff(vars, escapedVars)

  # get output prefix/suffix as string
  lhs <- rlang::f_lhs(formula) %>%
    all.vars()

  # get operation as string
  # deparse() can have line breaks; paste0() brings it back to one line
  rhs <- rlang::f_rhs(formula) %>%
    deparse() %>%
    paste0(collapse = "")

  # dummy function to cover for bquote escaping
  . <- function(x) x

  for (i in colNames) {
    if (isPrefix) {
      aliases <- paste0(vars, separator, i)
      newCol  <- paste0(lhs,  separator, i)
    } else {
      aliases <- paste0(i, separator, vars)
      newCol  <- paste0(i, separator, lhs)
    }

    if (length(lhs) == 0) newCol <- i

    mapping <- rlang::list2(!!!aliases)
    names(mapping) <- vars
    mapping <- do.call(wrapr::qc, mapping)

    df <- rlang::expr(wrapr::let(
      mapping,
      df %>% dplyr::mutate(!!newCol := ...RHS...)
    )) %>%
      deparse() %>%
      gsub(
        pattern = "...RHS...",
        replacement = rhs
      ) %>%
      {eval(parse(text = .))}
  }

  return(df)
}
```

It takes in a vector of names representing each "set" and a one- or two-sided formula representing the desired operation to be applied to each operation.

If the formula is one-sided, the name of the resulting column is the same as the set's; if it's two-sided, the column's name is the concatenation of the set's name and whatever was given on the left-hand side (so `x ~ a * b` results in columns `x_data1` and `x_data2`, for example).

```
df %>%
    NCHUtils::mutateSet(
        c("data1", "data2"),
        ~ a * b
    )
#>   id   a_data1   a_data2   b_data1   b_data2     static     data1      data2
#> 1  1 0.9148060 0.5190959 0.4577418 0.9400145 0.90403139 0.4187449 0.48795773
#> 2  2 0.9370754 0.7365883 0.7191123 0.9782264 0.13871017 0.6738624 0.72055016
#> 3  3 0.2861395 0.1346666 0.9346722 0.1174874 0.98889173 0.2674467 0.01582162
#> 4  4 0.8304476 0.6569923 0.2554288 0.4749971 0.94666823 0.2121203 0.31206942
#> 5  5 0.6417455 0.7050648 0.4622928 0.5603327 0.08243756 0.2966743 0.39507089
```

If an operation should also include columns which aren't part of the set (i.e, if we wanted to do `a * b + static`), the formula also accepts `bquote`-style escaping:

```
df %>%
    NCHUtils::mutateSet(
        c("data1", "data2"),
        x ~ a * b + .(static)
    )
#>   id   a_data1   a_data2   b_data1   b_data2     static   x_data1   x_data2
#> 1  1 0.9148060 0.5190959 0.4577418 0.9400145 0.90403139 1.3227763 1.3919891
#> 2  2 0.9370754 0.7365883 0.7191123 0.9782264 0.13871017 0.8125726 0.8592603
#> 3  3 0.2861395 0.1346666 0.9346722 0.1174874 0.98889173 1.2563384 1.0047134
#> 4  4 0.8304476 0.6569923 0.2554288 0.4749971 0.94666823 1.1587885 1.2587377
#> 5  5 0.6417455 0.7050648 0.4622928 0.5603327 0.08243756 0.3791119 0.4775084
```

In fact, this all works even if some of the data isn't in the dataframe but in the environment (i.e., if `static` were a variable in the environment instead of a column).

---

This was very much a jury-rigged solution (that weird `...RHS...` which is later replaced via `deparse()/gsub()` was a workaround for the problem in the linked question above), so I'm sure there's much to improve.

A feature-request might be too much to ask for, but if anyone can see how to do this trivially, that'd be great: a particular desire would be for this to accept `rlang`-style expansion (`!!` and `!!!`), which would make it easier to use this function in other NSE functions: i.e. a function which applies a `mutateSet` operation with `x + y`, but `x` and `y` are actually placeholders for the actual variables which will be given by the user. I'm currently writing precisely such a function and have had to instead write the entire `mutateSet` call as an `rlang::expr()`, where I can then define the variables in the formula with `!!`, and only then evaluate the call with `eval()`.